# how to insert dates in a table with sql and node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

hi my program don't work good i want insert the dates in a table but the cmd say *undefined*. the name of the table is noticia and the name of the database is news somebody may help me please

````
controller.list = (req, res) =>{
    req.getConnection((err, conn ) => {
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM noticia', (err, rows) =>{
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            }
            res.render('vista', {
                data: rows
            });
        });
    });
};

controller.save = (req, res) =>{
    const data = req.body;

    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        conn.query('INSERT INTO noticia SET ?', [data], (err, noticia) => {
            console.log(noticia);
            res.send('works');
        });
    })
}

module.exports = controller;```
---------CMD-----------
POST /add 200 93.794 ms - 5
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
servidor iniciado en el puerto 3000
undefined
POST /add 200 222.813 ms - 5
````

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT INTO` statement should be of the following format:

```sql
INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,...)
VALUES (v1,v2,...);
```

So you should format your statement like that.

For example, if I understood right:

```js
conn.query(
  "INSERT INTO mytable (username, text) VALUES (?, ?)",
  ['mkkekkonen', 'Hello world'],
  (err, msg) => console.log(msg),
);
```